# Acestream on Ubuntu 14.04, can i use it without DE?

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, streaming, vps

I installed acestream in a vps in this way:

```
echo "deb http://repo.acestream.org/ubuntu/ trusty main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo wget -O - http://repo.acestream.org/keys/acestream.public.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acestream-full
```

How can i download from source acestream without running graphical vlc or redirect to ffmpeg?

[acestreamengine log](http://pastebin.com/raw/NSqSVfvD)

[acestreamplayer log](http://pastebin.com/raw/Z7k3VcND)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error messages, I found this

> dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11

and this

> qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server
>   Which indicates the

which tell us, the graphical application `AceStream` cannot connect to X server. This is not surprising since you've installed it in a VPS. I suggest, you connect to your VPS graphically and run the application. In these case, remote desktops services like rdp can be used.

Comment: acestreamplayer is a fork of vlc, now you can run vlc without DE, with cvlc... i would support specific node, or redirect the stream on live youtube, or save a copy in vlc, but without DE